# Invoke screen commands from outside the session

Tags: gnu-screen

How can I send commands to a GNU Screen session? If I was using the session interactively, I'd type a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> escape sequence.

I need to send specific keystrokes to a GNU SCREEN session from other locations (could be a BASH Shell Script, a PHP page, whatever) to manipulate a program that only works as a "text-based UI" (like `lynx` or `vim`).  From time to time, I need to see what's going on in the SCREEN, so I export the view using the `hardcopy -h outputFile` command.

I need to "stuff" <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> then <kbd>:</kbd> into a screen, but it won't let me send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.  I tried this:

> **$** screen -S test -p 0 -X stuff '^A:'

But that only puts a colon (:) in the screen and ignores the ^A.

---

What I currently do (not working, need manual intervention to complete 3rd step):

1. Setup the Screen

   > **$** screen -S test
2. Inject commands to Screen

   > **$** screen -S test -p 0 -X stuff 'python^M'
   >   **$** screen -S test -p 0 -X stuff '42*9^M'
3. From within the screen, you can do
   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> then <kbd>:</kbd> to bring up the Screen's COMMAND input.  In that input, I type the following:

   > **:** hardcopy -h /tmp/scr-test.txt
4. I can then fetch the contents of the screen by `cat`-ing the file:

   > **$** cat /tmp/scr-test.txt
5. Which produces:

   > **$** cat /tmp/scr-test.txt
   >   justin@justin2012:~$ python
   >   Python 2.7.8 (default, Oct 18 2014, 12:50:18)
   >   [GCC 4.9.1] on linux2
   >   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
   >   >>> 42*9
   >   378
   >   >>>

Comment: What about using `eval`? As in `screen -S test -p 0 -X eval "hardcopy -h sample"`

Comment: or even just `screen -S test -p0 -X hardcopy out.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`screen -S test -p 0 -X stuff '^A:'` does work, but it does what it's supposed to do, not what you're trying to do: it sends the two characters `^A` and `:` to the application running in the screen window. That's what the `stuff` command does: it sends characters to the application running in the screen window, not to the screen interface.

What you want to do is send a command to screen itself, not to the application running inside screen. So don't use the `stuff` command: that's not what it's for. The feature you're looking for is simply `screen -X …`, of which `screen -X stuff …` is a special case.

For example, to make screen execute a `hardcopy` command, run

```
screen -S test -p 0 -X hardcopy -h outputFile
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what I wanted, users [Sukminder](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/28489/sukminder) and [lemonsqueeze](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/28431/lemonsqueeze) provided 2 variances of a way to access the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>:</kbd> interface, which is great.

[Sukminder](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/28489/sukminder) wrote:

> What about using `eval`? As in `screen -S test -p 0 -X eval "hardcopy -h sample"`

[lemonsqueeze](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/28431/lemonsqueeze) wrote:

> or even just `screen -S test -p0 -X hardcopy out.txt`

I've tested and both solutions work.  I think I'll still use [Sukminder](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/28489/sukminder)'s solution, since it allows me to keep the `-h` parameter.